# Conditionally apply sub-schema, based on another file's property

Tags: json, validation, conditional-statements, schema, jsonschema

Does json-schema allow to have conditional sub-schema based on the property value from another file?

Example:

**Jsons:**

**another.json**

```
{
  "honey": "honey"
}
```

**main.json**

```
{
  "hello": "abc"
}
```

**Schema**

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "hello": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": ["hello"],
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "another.json#/honey": {       -->> is this possible
        "const": "honey"
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {
      "hi": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "required": ["hi"]
  }
}
```

The main.json should fail validation screaming **"hi" is required** since, another.json has "honey" as value.

Now, changing another.json to

```
{
  "honey": "not_honey"
}
```

Should pass the validation for main.json

The question is

Answer (score 0):

No. JSON Schema has no notion of files, only "a JSON instance", of which only one can be validated at a time. You would need to combine them yourself in some way.